# Pooling configuration sizing for the Mule 4 Database Connnector

Tags: mulesoft, mule4, pooling, mule-connector

I want to do connection pooling in Database connector in Mule 4, but I'm not able to figure it out how to configure max and min pool size?
I am sending sending data which is of dynamic size. Hence what should an ideal size of max and min pool and why to use that particular size only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pool sizing is not related directly to the size of the data but to the number of concurrent operations. No one can tell you what size to use for your application. You need to understand how many concurrent database operations for a given database configuration you may have. The number may come from real experience, testing or an estimation. Anything else is bogus.

Comment: Is there any way through which I can configure how many concurrent database configuration is used in my case. Or if I go with estimation what factors to include while finding size of pool?

Comment: Each database server may have their own tools to monitor usage from the server side. For estimations try to define the number of concurrent clients or operations. You can perform load testing with different configurations and see the impact in performance. If you understand how to read thread dumps you can take several during execution and see how many threads are busy with database related classes.